# Andreev reflection and conservation of charge

Tags: superconductivity

I have an N-S junction.

I apply a voltage $+V$ on the normal metal.

But I choose $V$ such as $|eV| < \Delta$.

I know that my electron will be reflected as a hole.

But what I don't understand is the conservation of charge: a charge $-e$ comes from left to right and a charge $+e$ comes from the right to left.

So it is the same as if a charge $2e$ enters in the normal metal. But as $|eV| < \Delta$ it doesn't cross the superconductor.

So where has the charge gone? Does it respect the current conservation?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes it does, and this is explain in the article by Tinkham, M., Blonder, G., & Klapwijk, T. M. (1982). *Transition from metallic to tunneling regimes in superconducting microconstrictions: Excess current, charge imbalance, and supercurrent conversion.* Physical Review B, 25(7), 4515–4532. http://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.25.4515

Comment: Note that 2e can not enter in the normal metal, it has to enter in the superconducting region below the gap. Cooper pairs are collective modes/quasiparticles in a superconductors. They can exist below the gap, but in evanescent modes, and that's why one needs the proximity to a normal metal to get Andreev reflection.

Comment: you mean that when $eV\leq\Delta$, I will have quasiparticules in the superconductors **but** it will be evanescent waves. But this evanescent waves allow the charge conservation ?

Comment: Please check the article I refer to in my previous comment (Tinkham, Blonder and Klapwijk). You will see that the disappearance of 2e charge in the normal metal is converted in a 2e quasiparticle in the superconductor. Everything appear in the proximity to the S/N interface.